# How to enable Role Manager with SimpleMembership on ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wondering how to use the Role Manager feature with the `SimpleMembership` system included in ASP.NET MVC 4, specifically how to build a controller that manages all data associated with Roles, and using the `webpage_Roles` table that `SimpleMembership` creates when a project is created with a Internet Template. Is there a way to automate this within the Login/Register actions in the AccountController?

Comment: there is not admin built or template for user and role management for simple membership. I think that could be a good nuget package.

Comment: This link covers how to implement SimpleMembershipProvider and SimpleRoleProvider with user and role associations [http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/)

Comment: Might be a good read before deciding if you want to go down that road http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/ Also things like roles & membership can easily be managed with things like IIdentity & GenericPrincipal

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am no expert on ASP.NET MVC4 but as a task I have set for myself, I wanted to create Role Based site access.

ASP.NET MVC4 is an excellent resource! I do have complaints about the lack of information and difficulty to implement Roles in MVC4.

To achieve the task one can implement SimpleMembership and SimpleRoles. See the below links:

1. [Using SimpleMembership With ASP.NET WebPages](http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages) by Matthew M. Osborn
2. [SimpleMembership, Membership Providers, Universal Providers and the new ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC 4 templates](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) by Jon Galloway

The above two links explain a lot and have some very basic code examples but unfortunately the solution download is not available in the first URL.

In addition to the above:

1. [Customize the SimpleMembership in ASP.NET MVC 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2012/11/15/customize-the-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc-4-0.aspx) by thangchung
2. [ASP.NET MVC 4 Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-4-Sample-37924d68) on MSDN

This last article goes into a much better detail and also gives source code to peruse.

Answer (score 2):

In web.config add the following

```
<profile defaultProvider="SimpleProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleProfileProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" connectionStringName="DNMXEntities" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Comment: Just remember; to use this part of webconfig in your app webconfig; you should add roleManager enabled like this; <roleManager defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider" enabled="true">